# How to use environment variables for Git and cloud deployment

Tags: node.js, git, mongodb, heroku

tldr: What's the best practice for where to put things like secure credentials when deploying to the cloud?

I'm attempting to deploy my first MEAN app on Heroku. (This is the first time I've ever written a Node app, or tried to deploy anything to the cloud, so please bear with me.) I have the app running locally, but my Mongo connection string (using MongoLab) is currently hard-coded into a js file. I don't want that string showing up in my public Git repository, so I currently have it added to my .gitignore.

In Heroku, it looks like the deployment process involves pointing to a git repository and having the server pull down all the code from there and run it. This clearly won't work for me currently, as the Mongo connection string is not in the repo.

I'm assuming I'm supposed to use environment variables for this, and I know how to *read* environment vars in Node, but I'm very unclear on how to *set* those variables in the first place. I know you can set environment vars at the command line when you run a Node app, but having to do this every time I restart the app seems cumbersome, and I'm guessing there's a much better way to do it. I also am unclear on how to set the environment variables in Heroku, and I can't seem to find good documentation or tutorials on how to do either of these things. Am I missing something, or am I looking at the wrong paradigm in the first place?

Comment: You should read the documentation for [Heroku configuration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'd post my findings for the next person to look this up.

What I was having trouble with was not the specifics, but the general ideas behind doing this. In summation, Heroku allows you to use a local file, called ".env", in which you can set your environment variables. (In the format `VAR_NAME="value"`). Then, when you run "heroku local" from the command line, Heroku will launch your app in an environment that grabs those variables and passes them to the app, at localhost:5000. You simply add that .env file to your .gitignore, and it stays out of your code.

For actual deployment (via your git repository), Heroku has a web UI where you can set config vars (which, as far as I can tell, are synonymous with environment vars). This UI is available once you use `heroku create` and push your repository to the remote repo that has been created. You can also set remote environment vars via the command line, as mentioned by @metame.

Comment: Good to know for when using heroku. Nice built-in support for env vars when running locally.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an environment variable manager like [process-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/process-env) to set environment variables in a script for running your app manually/locally.

For Heroku, the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) specifies to use their [heroku-toolbet](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) command line tools. Use `heroku config:set VAR_NAME=value` to set an environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: See my own answer above.